# How to mask SSN showing xxxx-last 4 digit (9 digit ssn) on AG-GRID Column values

Tags: angular2-services, ag-grid, angular-pipe

> I am working on a Project in Angular where we have metadata object
>   where we are inserting (pushing the values) and showing that metadata
>   values to ag-grid. We have a column property (SSN) in that metadata
>   Which client wants to mask ,I have to show only last 4 digit of that
>   mask and other fields as XXXXX- .I dont want to change the value of
>   SSN as there is an edit button as well which allows to edit the values
>   EXCEPT SSN ,how should I mask the ssn in ag-grid ,the code would be
>   like [rowData]="rowData". rowData have values like in array with ssn
>   as one of the property.

```
<ag-grid-angular 
style="width: 500px; height: 500px;" 
class="ag-theme-balham"
[rowData]="rowData" 
[columnDefs]="columnDefs"
>
</ag-grid-angular>
```

Comment: @HDJEMAI can you help me

Comment: Can you post the code you've already tried?

Comment: @GregBurghardt I dont have the exact code but in my rowData I have the values like ssn  ,firstname,lastname and other values ,  for example  {0: {ssn: "123456789",firstname:"sarvesh"}, 1: {"ssn":"987654321",firstname:"rahul"}} where  0 ,1 are indexes ,I want to mask these SSN as XXXXX-LAST 4DIGIT VISIBLE but i dont want to change the object value .How to achieve that

Comment: Through angular pipes we can do something like this for individual properties  {{ssn | pipe}} which can transform data but the problem is here ag-grid where I am passing whole rowData values ,is there any columapi properties ag-grid provide which can transform the data only over web page not changing the value.

Comment: I think a better approach would be to mask the SSN server-side. It's not too hard to get the real SSN in the browser even if you mask it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Cell Renderer`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/#simple-cell-renderer-example) for this.

As shown in the example, you'll have to provide the `cellRenderer` with the `ColDef` for your column for `SSN`.

```
{field: 'gold', width: 100, cellRenderer: 'myCellRenderer'}
```

You can even provide a callback function for `cellRenderer` parameter while defining `ColDef` - which should return a `string`.

```
ssnColDef = {
  field: 'SSN',
  width: 100,
  cellRenderer = (param) => {
     // param.value will be the cell value
     // do string operations to mask the SSN value with XXX
     return 'XXXX' + param.value.substring(4, param.value.substring.length)
  }
}
```

Comment: paritosh,can you elaborate more , I have gone through the document , I need to create a cell renderer component for this ?  suppose now in my columdef  I have added cellrenderer like this columdef= {field :SSN ,width:100 ,cellRenderer: 'maskcellrenderer'} ,where should i provide this callback function .In maskcellrendere component there will be aginit() which will initilaze the params.

Answer (score 0):

If your SSN field is not editable, You can use a variable called maskedSSN in your TS file and then bind it with your HTML for display.

for displaying, get the last 4 digits of your SSN and use concat to form a masked SSN with XXXX included.

While sending it to backend again or for any other operations which include SSN value, use the original value of SSN.

Comment: Thnks @praveen rana for different approach but I guess the above approach suits more to have a callback function with cellrenderer